# Can Ruby return nothing?

Tags: ruby

Can I return nothing in ruby?

*Just for educational purpose*

For example:

```
myarray = [1,2,3]
myarray << some_method

def some_method
  if Date.today.day > 15
    return "Trololo"
  else
    return __NOTHING__
  end
end
```

So if today is 11'th March `myarray` won't add new item. I don't want `nil` - because `nil` is not nothing :)

And I understand, that I can use `if | unless` statement like `myarray << some_method if some_method` etc. I want to understand can I return **nothing** or every time in ruby I am returning **something** (least I can get is Nil Object)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Basically, what you are looking for is a *statement*. But Ruby doesn't have statements, only *expressions*. *Everything* is an expression, i.e. everything returns a value.

Answer (score 11):

No, you can't return nothing. In ruby you always return something (even if it's just `nil`) - no way around that.

Comment: That said, `nil` is supposed to represent the concept of 'nothing'.

Answer (score 6):

You can't return "nothing" from a method in ruby. As you point out you could conditionally add elements to your array. You can also invoke .compact on your array to remove all nil elements.

Answer (score 5):

You can't return a real Nothing with Ruby. Everything is a object. But you can create a fake Nothing to do it. See:

```
Nothing = Module.new # Same as module Nothing; end
class Array
  alias old_op_append <<
  def <<(other)
    if other == Nothing
      self
    else
      old_op_append(other)
    end
  end
end
```

This is ugly but works in your sample. (Nothing keeps being a object.)

Comment: Interesting hack. Can be usefull.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing does not mean anything to ruby from what i know :) You can define your own nothing though and throw it as much as possible. In ruby, if you do not explicitly return something, the last evaluated expression is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate Nothing with exceptions.

```
class NothingError < RuntimeError  
end  

def nothing
  raise NothingError
end

def foo x
  if x>0 then x else nothing end
end

def nothingness
  begin
    yield
  rescue NothingError
  end
end

a = [1,2,3]
nothingness { a << foo(4) }
nothingness { a << foo(0) }
```

Probably not a great idea however ...