# Can I tell if a method needs to return something in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am doing some metaprogramming in ruby and in the method_missing implementation I wonder If i can tell if the call site is being used in an assignment ?

For example :

```
x = special_function 'param'
```

would be caught by the method_missing implementation. I would like to know if I can tell if the function was invoked like this :

```
special_function 'param'
```

I.e. without a left hand side on the assignment.

Is it possible in ruby to tell the difference between the above two examples in code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't think this is possible, simply because every method always returns *something* and evaluating a method is independent of the context in which it is called.

The assignment is incidental in this case and just happens to make use of what the method returns.

Is there a reason you want to distinguish these calls? Maybe there are other ways to look at the same problem by following a naming convention in your methods to help you separate their uses.

Comment: +1 I totally agree with this answer, and in particular with existence of "other ways to look at the same problem"

Comment: Thanks that makes perfect sense. Reason I want to distinguish the calls is that the method that I am dynamically creating would need to do extra work if there is a return value expected. I am dynamically wrapping a message bus and some of the calls into the message bus are 'fire-and-forget' and some are 'request-reply' ...

Comment: The way I usually see things when it comes to methods, is if it behaves differently in different cases, maybe it should be another method. If that isn't an option for you, maybe a parameter with a default value could solve your problem.

Comment: I'd suggest two methods two - i.e: `publish` for 'fire and forget' and `send` when expecting a reply.

Answer (score 1):

Here is no any difference for your case, as I understand.

Ruby will invoke your code from right to left.

So it will try to execute firstly:

```
special_function 'param'
```

And then it'll asign the result to `x`.

So if `special_function` method is not defined will throw it to `method missing` and if it will handle it somehow it will return some vaue back. And `x` will be assigned to this actual value

**PS** as I read @ne0lithic_coder answer looks like I've understand your question wrong. You can see this topic: [Can Ruby return nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267412/can-ruby-return-nothing)

**PPS**
If you don't want to assign `x` in some cases you can try:

```
val = special_function 'param'
x = val unless val.nil? # if val
```